# Subscription is not being updated when changed

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, subscription

header.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    //for auto authentication
    this.userIsAuthenticated = this.globalAuthService.getIsAuth();
    //subscribe to listener for status of auth
    this.authListenerSubscription = this.globalAuthService.getAuthStatusListener()
      .subscribe( isAuthenticated  => {
        //set based off result of above call to authService
        this.userIsAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
      });

    //TODO figure out how to fix the bug of admin not reloading on signin because header is not reloading
    this.adminAuthService.getIsAdmin();
    this.adminListenerSubscription = this.adminAuthService.getAdminStatusListener()
      .subscribe( isAdmin  => {
        console.log(isAdmin)
        //set based off result of above call to authService
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
        console.log(this.isAdmin);
      });
  }

  //for logout
  onLogout(){
    this.globalAuthService.logoutUser();
    this.adminListenerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.isAdmin = false;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(){
    //unsubscribe to listener
    this.authListenerSubscription.unsubscribe();
    this.adminListenerSubscription.unsubscribe();
  }
```

admin-auth.service.ts

```
private adminStatusListener = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(null);
  private adminCreationStatusListener = new Subject<boolean>();
  private adminUsersUpdated = new Subject<{adminUsers: UserData[]}>();
  private isAdmin = false;
  private adminUsers: UserData[] = [];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {}
  //to check if admin
  getIsAdmin(){
    const userId = localStorage.getItem('userId');
    const userData = { id: userId };
    if (!userId){
      return false;
    }
    //find user that matches and tell if admin
    this.http.post<{ isAdmin: boolean }>(BACKEND_URL + 'find', userData)
      .subscribe( response => {
        this.isAdmin = response.isAdmin;
        this.adminStatusListener.next(this.isAdmin);
      }, error => {
        this.adminStatusListener.next(false);
    });
      return this.getAdminStatusListener();
  }

getAdminStatusListener(){
    return this.adminStatusListener.asObservable();
  }
```

login.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
    //form mapping
    this.form = new FormGroup({
      'email': new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required, Validators.email]}),
      //password must contain one digit, one lowercase alpha, one uppercase alpha, one special character, and be 8 >= x <= 32 characters
      'password': new FormControl(null, {validators: [Validators.required]})
    });

    //for handling error
    this.authStatusSub = this.globalAuthService.getAuthStatusListener().subscribe(
      authStatus =>{
        this.isLoading = false;
      });
  }

  onLogin(){
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      return
    }
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.globalAuthService.loginUser(this.form.value.email, this.form.value.password);
    this.adminAuthService.getIsAdmin();
    this.form.reset();
  }
```

app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: GlobalAuthInterceptor, multi: true },
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
    [Data],
    [AdminAuthService]
  ],
```

So I'm trying to update the subscription that is in ngOnInit in the header component when I sign in on the login component.  The subscription updates properly if I refresh the page because the ngOnInit is fired when the header component loads.  The issue is, I don't want to reload the page everytime someone logs in.  Therefore I need the subscription in header.component to update when a user uses the login function on the login component.  Please help

Comment: are you able to provide a link to a minimum working example? It sounds like you may be subscribing to a source observable after it has completed.

Comment: So the observable works fine.  It just first starts out as false.  Once someone logs in, it becomes true and I need the header  component to pick up on that change

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be subscribing to the admin observables after they are complete or

What happens if you just return the behavior subject? This will always return the latest values.

```
// why not just expose the behavior subject? e.g.
getAdminStatusListener(){
  return this.adminStatusListener;
}
```

I would also set up your subscribe code before you call the method to update the admin user. e.g.

```
    // TODO figure out how to fix the bug of admin not reloading on signin because header is not reloading
    
    this.adminListenerSubscription = this.adminAuthService.getAdminStatusListener()
      .pipe(filter(v => v !== null)) // filter initial null value of Behavior Subject
      .subscribe( isAdmin  => {
        console.log(isAdmin)
        //set based off result of above call to authService
        this.isAdmin = isAdmin;
        console.log(this.isAdmin);
      });

    this.adminAuthService.getIsAdmin();
```

Another troubleshooting route would be to add the subscription to the adminListener into the html template. e.g.

```
   // .ts file
   this.adminListenerSubscription = this.adminAuthService.getAdminStatusListener()
      .pipe(filter(v => v !== null)); // filter initial null value of Behavior Subject

    this.adminAuthService.getIsAdmin();

  // .html
<pre>{{adminListenerSubscription | async}}</pre>
```

This will show you if the issue is not with the observables and with ng's change detection

Good luck.

Comment: So it is an issue with ng's change detection because if I do a fulle refresh on the page the observable works.  I also tried what you commented and it didn't seem to work.